# Unable to find Proxy Servers

Tags: proxy, vpn, mac

I'm totally new to Tor, Yeah I know, the newbie. So I'm running a Mac. with Ivacy VPN. Also running Tor 6.5.1. Getting the "Unable to find Proxy Servers". Didn't do any modifications just started happening, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work without the VPN?

Comment: No, All other browsers work fine no problems. The Tor thing happened all by itself

Comment: So if you don't use the VPN then Tor Browser still doesn't work? I'd probably suggest uninstalling it and removing the `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data` folder then reinstalling it.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks for the help, good to have a Mac person replying.

Comment: canonizing ironize - you are the man, I'm so embarrassed, dude, I've been a Mac tech retired now for over 35 years. You know how you over think shit. Well that's exactly what I was doing with this one. I got dumb founded when it just stopped working. Thanks again man, works like a charm. I'm new to this forum, how do I mark it as resolved, want to make sure you get whatever credit is yours.